# how could I get the password hash in Django ORM?

Tags: django, password-hash

I want to get the user by a password so when I type the following code

```
User.objects.get(password='test')
```

I get an error and I already know what is error is talking about which occurs because the password has been hashed but I want to get it, so what is the trick I need here?

Comment: You don't. The hash is randomized, so you can not do this. Even if you thus have *a* hash for a password, you can not filter with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an error and I already know what is error is talking about which occurs because the password has been hashed but I want to get it, so what is the trick I need here?

You **don't**. The hash algorithm makes use of a *random* value (named the [*salt* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))) that is stored together with the hashed password. This thus means that for a given password, there is not a *single* hash, but an infinite number. For a fixed salt size, the number of hash results is, strictly speaking, finite, but still the number of hashes is that large that it is infeasible to generate/test all.

Salt is used to prevent against a set of pre-comuted hashes (also known as [*rainbow table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)). By making use of salt, it is almost impossible to compute the hash for every possible salt for a given set of passwords, and it thus makes the problem of reversing the hashes to passwords harder.

You thus should iterate over the `User` objects, and use the [**`.check_password(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password):

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    if user.check_password('test'):
        # … we found a user with password 'test'
        pass
```

For more information, see the [*How Django stores passwords* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords).

Comment: ok, but I'm trying to understand the authenticate(email=email, password=password) method in Django so the closest example I got is when I type User.objects.get(email='example@gmail.com', id=1) in this case I can log in by that if it was correct so how can substitute the authenticate method and do something like the ORM I typed but at this moment will be used by a password instead of id?

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin: it will fetch the `User` object with the given *`email`*, it can do that quite fast, and *then*, after retrieving the `User` object, it will call `check_password` at the Django/Python level. This will look at the hashed password, obtain the last, rehash with the given salt, and then checks if the hashes match. But the lookup part is done with the email, or with another identifier (`username`, `id`, etc.)